# Linq usage of Contains

Tags: c#, .net, linq

I am trying to retrieve a list of employees from an specific manager. I find first the manager shift and then a list of managers on this shift.The third query needs to retrieve all employees belonging to this managers list. I don't know what's wrong, but I don't get any results. I appreciate your help

```
   //Determine shift of current user
    int shiftId = (from s in db.webpages_UsersInRoles
                   where s.UserId == userId
                   select s.ShiftId).Single();
    var ManagerId = (from g in db.tblManager
                      where g.ShiftId == shiftId
                      select g.UserID).ToList();

var employees = (from e in db.tblEmployee
                 where ManagerId.Contains(e.ShiftId.Value)                            
                 select e).ToList();
```

Comment: Is ShiftId.Value and Manager same thing? I mean you are trying to get a match of shiftId in a list of managers. Is it okay with your data structure.

Comment: Shouldn't it be: where e.ShiftId==shiftId in the last query?

Comment: I think you need to present the code for all the business objects at stake here. Otherwise it is just guesswork.

Comment: Yes, you're right ManagerId and ShiftID does not match. I corrected it to  GlId.Contains(e.GlId.Value) and it is working, thanks

Answer (score 0):

Your last query is checking against e.ShiftId where it should be against e.EmployeeId

```
var employees = (from e in db.tblEmployee
                 where ManagerId.Contains(e.EmployeeId.Value)                            
                 select e).ToList();
```